# Log level in 0.8.2 not correctly configured?

Tags: logging, docker, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I'm using marathon 0.8.2 and the mesosphere docker image (tag v0.8.2). I'm passing the `--logging_level warn` flag to the daemon, but I'm still seeing all the health checks come through (log level INFO).

```
47f1eff08164        mesosphere/marathon:v0.8.2            "./bin/start --maste   About an hour ago   Up About an hour                        mesos_marathon
```

A snippet from docker inspect:

```
  "CMD": [
        "--master",
        "zk://zk_host1:2181,zk_host2:2181,zk_host3:2181/mesos",
        "--zk",
        "zk://zk_host1:2181,zk_host2:2181,zk_host3:2181/marathon",
        "--hostname",
        "marathon_host",
        "--max_tasks_per_offer",
        "10",
        "--http_port",
        "80",
        "--logging_level",
        "warn"
    ],
```

The parameters via `ps`:

```
java -jar ./bin/../target/marathon-assembly-0.8.2.jar --master zk://zk_host1:2181,zk_host2:2181,zk_host3:2181/mesos --zk zk://zk_host1:2181,zk_host2:2181,zk_host3:2181/marathon --hostname marathon_host --max_tasks_per_offer 10 --http_port 80 --logging_level warn
```

However, when I look at `docker logs mesos_marathon`, I see lots of INFO:

> [INFO] [06/16/2015 15:49:25.302] [marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://marathon/user/$f] Received health result [Healthy(microbot.edb72ab0-143e-11e5-8fb0-56847afe9799,2015-06-16T15:46:24.346Z,2015-06-16T15:49:25.206Z)]
>
> [INFO] [06/16/2015 15:49:25.302] [marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://marathon/user/$f] Received health result:[Healthy(microbot.e6946214-143e-11e5-8fb0-56847afe9799,2015-06-16T15:46:24.346Z,2015-06-16T15:49:25.206Z)]
>
> [INFO] [06/16/2015 15:49:25.302] [marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://marathon/user/$f] Received health result: [Healthy(microbot.ea257847-143e-11e5-8fb0-56847afe9799,2015-06-16T15:46:24.346Z,2015-06-16T15:49:25.206Z)]
>
> [INFO] [06/16/2015 15:49:25.302] [marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://marathon/user/$f] Received health result: [Healthy(microbot.ff9ac8c5-143e-11e5-8fb0-56847afe9799,2015-06-16T15:46:24.346Z,2015-06-16T15:49:25.207Z)]
>
> [INFO] [06/16/2015 15:49:25.302] [marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://marathon/user/$f] Received health result:  [Healthy(microbot.edbf8e46-143e-11e5-8fb0-56847afe9799,2015-06-16T15:46:24.346Z,2015-06-16T15:49:25.207Z)]
>
> [INFO] [06/16/2015 15:49:25.303] [marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://marathon/user/$f] Received health result:  [Healthy(microbot.f888a2eb-143e-11e5-8fb0-56847afe9799,2015-06-16T15:46:24.346Z,2015-06-16T15:49:25.208Z)]
>
> [INFO] [06/16/2015 15:49:25.303] [marathon-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://marathon/user/$f] Received health result:  [Healthy(microbot.edbc80f0-143e-11e5-8fb0-56847afe9799,2015-06-16T15:46:24.346Z,2015-06-16T15:49:25.208Z)]

I'm certainly missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Akka does not use a particular logging backend, it just prints to standard out. To configure Akka logging please refer to :http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/logging.html.

You can also get a more fine grained control over marathon logging using the `/logging` endpoint. So visit `<marathon_url>/logging` to configure logging in Marathon at runtime